# Conditional Format in Excel spread sheet

Tags: vba, excel

[Picture of some data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j7U8.png)

Here my requirement
1. just the lowest value of each every row will change its color in Blue (If the lowest value is in more than one cell)
2. If the lowest value is in only one color the cell have the yellow color.

These are all done with only cell which is having the lowest value of each every row.

Comment: What concrete problem do you have?

Comment: please provide a question, what Problem do you have, what have you tried ? have you allready written code ?

Comment: On the home tab you can find Conditional Formatting. If you'll have look at it, all will become clear

Answer (score 0):

The formulas I created below are set for columns A to N, adjust as needed.

Conditional format the cell A1 (adjust as needed) with both these rules:

```
=IF(IF(A1=SMALL($A1:$N1,1),COUNTIF($A1:$N1,SMALL($A1:$N1,1)),0)>=2,1,0)
```

Mark this one with 'Stop If True' and colour the background yellow.

Next rule for the same cell:

```
=IF(A1=SMALL($A1:$N1,1),1,0)
```

Colour the background blue.

Use the format painter to copy the rule to the other cells in that row.

Cells should now change background colour as required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. It's not perfect but should do what you want.

```
Sub ConditionalFormat()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer, u As Integer, myCount As Integer
    Dim lRow As Long, lColumn As Long
    Dim myMin As Double
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        'Count last row
        lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
            After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False).Row
        'Count last column
        lColumn = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
            After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False).Column
        'Remove currency numberformat
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRow, lColumn)).NumberFormat = "General"

        For x = 1 To lRow
            'Find smallest value and count how many times it shows up
            myMin = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(.Rows(x))
            myCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Rows(x), myMin)
            'Color cells that appear more than once blue
            If myCount > 1 Then
                For u = 1 To lColumn
                    If .Cells(x, u).Value = myMin Then
                        .Cells(x, u).Interior.Color = 15773696
                    End If
                Next u
            'Color cells that appear once yellow
            ElseIf myCount = 1 Then
                For u = 1 To lColumn
                    If .Cells(x, u).Value = myMin Then
                        .Cells(x, u).Interior.Color = 65535
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next u
            End If
        Next x
    'Return currency format
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRow, lColumn)).NumberFormat = "[$£-809]#,##0.00"

    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

End Sub
```